# Why does this script cause problems only on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I had to add a job in a multibranch pipeline.
The goal was to automatically install a plugin in jira.
The code runs perfectly fine because I tested it in a Unit Test.
But when I put it as a scripted pipeline on Jenkins, it does not do what it should do.
The goal is to install the plugin on jira, but when I run it on Jenkins it will not be installed.
Also I do not get any json Response, which I get in my JUnit Test.
I really do not know what is different on Jenkins. I already found it weird that I have to approve every single method in my script. Did someone have a similar issue on jenkins before.
I really appreciate your help.

```
 @Test
    public void test_install_plugin() throws IOException {


        String jsonBody = "{\"pluginUri\": \"http://myServer/job/element/job/mybranch\", \"pluginName\": \"myPlugin\"}";
        String token = "-6485649001990379871";

        String jiraPath="myServer/rest/plugins/1.0/";
        String query = "token="+token;
        String url = jiraPath+"?"+query;
        URL jiraURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection jiraURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)jiraURL.openConnection();


        jiraURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        jiraURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        jiraURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Length",String.valueOf(jsonBody.length()));
        jiraURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Accept", "application/json");
        jiraURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/vnd.atl.plugins.install.uri+json");
        jiraURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic YWRXXXXXXtaW4=");
        jiraURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = jiraURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            byte[] input = jsonBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            os.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            os.close();
            System.out.println("responseCode of install request: " + jiraURLConnection.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {

          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jiraURLConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
          StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
              String responseLine = null;
              while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  response.append(responseLine.trim());
              }
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
         }
         catch(IOException ex)
         {
             System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
         }
         finally
         {
              br.close();
              jiraURLConnection.disconnect();
         }
    }
```